# Use specified quanlifier in grep to retrieve satisfied vocabulary

Tags: bash, grep

I try to grab words from a file:

```
    $ grep -o '\*\*[^*]*\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md | grep -v -e "Origin" -e "Etymology"
```

and get output:

```
    **circumstance**
    **case**
    **condition**
    **Anxiety**
    **anxiety**
    **the state of feeling nervous or worried that sth bad is going to happen**
    **a worry or fear about sth**
    **a strong feeling of wanting to do sth or of wanting sth to happen**
```

The result I intend is:

```
  # only words
    **circumstance**
    **case**
    **condition**
    **Anxiety**
    **anxiety**
```

Refactored code with specified quatifiers `{,20}`:

```
$ grep -o '\*\*[^*]{,20}\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md
```

Unfortunately, it return None.

How to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `-E` flag:

```
$ grep -E -o '\*\*[^*]{,20}\*\*' input | grep -v -e "Origin" -e "Etymology"
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```

You can also just match text that contains only alpha characters:

```
$ grep -o '\*\*[[:alpha:]]*\*\*' input
```

For `input`, I used your original output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already

```
grep -o '\*\*[^*]*\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md
```

add a space in `[^*]*`, ie. `[^* ]*`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that
{start, end}, the start qualifier should not be omitted.

```
$ grep -E -o '\*\*[^*]{0,20}\*\*' input | grep -v -e "Origin" -e 
"Etymology"
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```